# @ModelAttribute is synchronized?

Tags: java, spring, spring-3

I have a problem with Spring 3.
Anyone could tell me, method like this in controller:

```
@ModelAttribute("nameAtributte")
public Customer getCustomerInfo(HttpServletRequest request) {
     return service.getCustomer(request);
}
```

is synchronized ?

Answer (score 1):

Of cause this method is not synchronized. But it seems I understand how you have come to this conclusion. I used the following code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/url")
public class ModelAtrCotroller {

    @ModelAttribute
    public String modelAtr() {
        return "foo";
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

I placed a break-point in the `modelAtr` method and sent two requests to the url from two different tabs of the same browser. And it seemed that the method is synchronized, since serving the second request did not start until I've released the break-point during the first serving. I assume that single "keep-alive" connection is used by the browser and second request simply did not start from the browser until the response to the first request was not received.

I used two different browsers for the two concurrent request and had two application server threads both paused on the same break-point in the middle of `modelAtr` method.